# Why is `pthread_testcancel` called multiple times in the `nanosleep` implementation of winpthreads?

Tags: c, windows, pthreads, posix, pthreads-win32

The `nanosleep` implementation of winpthreads, which is a port of POSIX threads to Windows, calls `pthread_testcancel` multiple times in its implementation.

`nanosleep` in [[nanosleep.c](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/mingw-w64-libraries/winpthreads/src/nanosleep.c)] calls `pthread_delay_np_ms` which is not exported and does the actual sleeping. This is the code of `pthread_delay_np_ms` in [[thread.c](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/mingw-w64-libraries/winpthreads/src/thread.c)].

```
int
pthread_delay_np_ms (DWORD to)
{
  struct _pthread_v *s = __pthread_self_lite ();

  if (!to)
    {
      pthread_testcancel ();
      Sleep (0);
      pthread_testcancel ();
      return 0;
    }
  pthread_testcancel ();
  if (s->evStart)
    WaitForSingleObject (s->evStart, to);
  else
    Sleep (to);
  pthread_testcancel ();
  return 0;
}
```

You can see `pthread_testcancel` is called multiple times for some reason.

What is the reason for the additional code while I think this could be as simple as follows?

```
int
pthread_delay_np_ms (DWORD to)
{
  Sleep (to);
  return 0;
}
```

What does `pthread_testcancel` achieve? Also, a side question is why is `WaitForSingleObject` preferred over `Sleep` when a dummy event handle is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another thread can call `pthread_cancel` in which case `WaitForSingleObject` will return immediately and the thread will be killed while your simple `Sleep` would keep a now pointless thread around for an unknown amount of time.

Why they are calling `pthread_testcancel` before `Sleep(0)` and `if (s->evStart)`, I don't know. Maybe you should ask the authors directly if you care that much about it. I assume they are there for a reason...

Comment: I can now see a difference between `WaitForSingleObject` and `Sleep` in this case, but doesn't `Sleep` by itself make the OS execute other pending threads?

Comment: Oh, I see. `pthread_cancel` can do some more things..